# Alternative way to request cross-site AJAX request in development

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain

AJAX request from http://localhost:8080 to http://foo.com in AngularJS app was failed because browsers don't let cross-site request and browser say:

> "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

But there are another ways to solve using **JSONP** or may be writing extra code on server side but I don't want to do that for development phase.

Is there any alternative ways to make cross-site without any configuration on server side and any writing extra code in development phase (not production)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pure javascript alternative that uses a proxy to bypass this constraint.

It is called XDomain:

https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

Step 1: Put this proxy.html file on the root of your server project:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/jpillora/xdomain/0.7.3/dist/xdomain.min.js" master="*"></script>
```

Step 2: Add this script to the client:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/jpillora/xdomain/0.7.3/dist/xdomain.min.js" slave="http://foo.com/proxy.html"></script>
```

And thats it!
Have fun.

Comment: Yeah! That's great but still a little writing code :)

Comment: Given that the OP explicitly asked *Is there any alternative ways to make cross-site **without any configuration on server side***, this doesn’t seem like an actual answer to the question—since for XDomain you need to “add a proxy.html on the domain you wish to communicate with”. If you control the domain you wish to communicate with to the point  you can put a file at the domain, you can also put, e.g., an `.htaccess` file there to send the required CORS headers. So basically, XDomain is just intended to be a more convenient way to handle the server side instead of doing CORS config there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the alternative way is just installing this [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). No needs to write any extra code. But I don't know how security affected this plugin is.